# How to remove Salesforce standard Navigation Panel in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli

From the record page I am opening LWC using button.
On that page I dont want Salesforce standard Navigation Panel including.
[image]

I want to remove whole part marked in red in the image.

Please let me know if this is possible or not